# Can't save audio to phone using media player in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to make a soundboard where you user can play and stop sound as well as save the sounds to phone.

I have set it up fine but the save will not work. I'm not getting any error and not sure whats wrong. I get the box to come up saying to save it, but when clicked does nothing. Using ViewPagerIndicator.
Any help?
Sorry only a beginner.

```
public class Question1 extends Fragment {

    private AdView adView;
    Button button01;
    Button button02;
    Button button03;
    Button button04;
    Button button05;
    Button button06;
    Button button07;
    Button button08;
    Button button09;
    Button button10;
    Button button11;
    Button button12;
    Button button13;
    Button button14;
    Button button15;
    Button button16;
    Button button17;
    Button button18;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Long Press To Save As Ringtone.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.question1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        button01 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button02 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button02);
        button03 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button03);
        button04 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button04);
        button05 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button05);
        button06 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button06);
        button07 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button07);
        button08 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button08);
        button09 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button09);
        button10 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button10);
        button11 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button11);
        button12 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button12);
        button13 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button13);
        button14 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button14);
        button15 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button15);
        button16 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button16);
        button17 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button17);
        button18 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button18);


        // import sound files
        final MediaPlayer sound01 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound01);
        final MediaPlayer sound02 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound02);
        final MediaPlayer sound03 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound03);
        final MediaPlayer sound04 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound04);
        final MediaPlayer sound05 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound05);
        final MediaPlayer sound06 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound06);
        final MediaPlayer sound07 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound07);
        final MediaPlayer sound08 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound08);
        final MediaPlayer sound09 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound09);
        final MediaPlayer sound10 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound10);
        final MediaPlayer sound11 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound11);
        final MediaPlayer sound12 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound12);
        final MediaPlayer sound13 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound13);
        final MediaPlayer sound14 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound14);
        final MediaPlayer sound15 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound15);
        final MediaPlayer sound16 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound16);
        final MediaPlayer sound17 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound17);

        // play sound files on clicks
        Button s02 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button02); 
        s02.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote02));
        s02.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound01.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound01.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s02);

        Button s03 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button03); 
        s03.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote03));
        s03.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound02.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound02.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s03);

        Button s04 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button04); 
        s04.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote04));
        s04.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound03.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound03.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s04);

        Button s05 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button05); 
        s05.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote05));
        s05.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound04.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound04.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s05);

        Button s06 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button06); 
        s06.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote06));
        s06.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound05.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound05.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s06);

        Button s07 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button07); 
        s07.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote07));
        s07.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound06.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound06.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s07);

        Button s08 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button08); 
        s08.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote08));
        s08.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound07.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound07.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s08);

        Button s09 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button09); 
        s09.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote09));
        s09.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound08.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound08.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s09);

        Button s10 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button10); 
        s10.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote10));
        s10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound09.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound09.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s10);

        Button s11 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button11); 
        s11.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote11));
        s11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound10.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound10.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s11);

        Button s12 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button12); 
        s12.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote12));
        s12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound11.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound11.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s12);

        Button s13 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button13); 
        s13.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote13));
        s13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound12.prepare();
                } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound12.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s13);

        Button s14 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button14); 
        s14.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote14));
        s14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound13.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound13.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s14);

        Button s15 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button15); 
        s15.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote15));
        s15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound14.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound14.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s15);

        Button s16 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button16); 
        s16.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote16));
        s16.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound15.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound15.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s16);

        Button s17 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button17); 
        s17.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote17));
        s17.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound16.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {    
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound16.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s17);

        Button s18 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button18); 
        s18.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote18));
        s18.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound17.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sound17.start();                
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s18);

        final Button s01 = getView().findViewById(R.id.button01);
        s01.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote01));
        s01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sound01.isPlaying()) {
                    sound01.pause();
                    sound01.seekTo(0);
                }

                if (sound02.isPlaying()) {
                    sound02.pause();
                    sound02.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound03.isPlaying()) {
                    sound03.pause();
                    sound03.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound04.isPlaying()) {
                    sound04.pause();
                    sound04.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound05.isPlaying()) {
                    sound05.pause();
                    sound05.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound06.isPlaying()) {
                    sound06.pause();
                    sound06.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound07.isPlaying()) {
                    sound07.pause();
                    sound07.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound08.isPlaying()) {
                    sound08.pause();
                    sound08.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound09.isPlaying()) {
                    sound09.pause();
                    sound09.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound10.isPlaying()) {
                    sound10.pause();
                    sound10.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound11.isPlaying()) {
                    sound11.pause();
                    sound11.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound12.isPlaying()) {
                    sound12.pause();
                    sound12.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound13.isPlaying()) {
                    sound13.pause();
                    sound13.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound14.isPlaying()) {
                    sound14.pause();
                    sound14.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound15.isPlaying()) {
                    sound15.pause();
                    sound15.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound16.isPlaying()) {
                    sound16.pause();
                    sound16.seekTo(0);
                }
                if (sound17.isPlaying()) {
                    sound17.pause();
                    sound17.seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        });

        registerForContextMenu(s01);
    }

    // perform save functions on long press
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone/Notification");    
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        if (item.getTitle() == "Ringtone/Notification" {
            function1(item.getItemId());
        } else {
            return false;
        }  
        return true;  
    }  

    // detect which button was clicked, save as a ringtone with strings.xml
    public boolean function1(int ressound) {  

        //----
        String soundname = "";

        switch (ressound) {
            case R.id.button02:
                ressound = R.raw.sound01;
                soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote02));
                break;
            case R.id.button03:
                ressound = R.raw.sound02;
                soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote03));
                break;
            case R.id.button04:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound03;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote04));
                 break;
            case R.id.button05:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound04;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote05));
                 break;
            case R.id.button06:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound05;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote06));
                 break;
            case R.id.button07:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound06;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote07));
                 break;
            case R.id.button08:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound07;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote08));
                 break;
            case R.id.button09:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound08;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote09));
                 break;
            case R.id.button10:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound09;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote10));
                 break;
            case R.id.button11:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound10;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote11));
                 break;
            case R.id.button12:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound11;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote12));
                 break;
            case R.id.button13:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound12;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote13));
                 break;
            case R.id.button14:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound13;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote14));
                 break;
            case R.id.button15:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound14;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote15));
                 break;
            case R.id.button16:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound15;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote16));
                 break;
            case R.id.button17:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound16;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote17));
                 break;
            case R.id.button18:
                 ressound = R.raw.sound17;
                 soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote18));
                 break;
        }

        //and so on and so on.....
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream fIn = getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
        int size=0;

        try {
            size = fIn.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            fIn.read(buffer);
            fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        }

        String path = "/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
        String filename = soundname + ".ogg";

        boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
        if (!exists) {
            new File(path).mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream save;
        try {
             save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
             save.write(buffer);
             save.flush();
             save.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             return false;
        }

        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

        File k = new File(path, filename);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundname);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "NapoleonHill");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        //Insert it into the database
         getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

        String i = "Saved as Ringtone.";
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
   }

   //----  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @DavidWallace It's not duplicate. The link you provided is a reference for his issue.

Comment: @PareshMayani Are you saying that every single question which amounts to "my code doesn't work because I'm using `==` instead of `.equals` to compare strings" should be left open, because in every case the code is different?  That's really not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Agree with your point about closing question but for this question, it can't be stated directly that its a duplicate of the question you shared. But it should be closed by selecting "why my code isn't working" option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch

```
item.getTitle() == "Ringtone/Notification"
```

to

```
"Ringtone/Notification".equals(item.getTitle());
```

The following question is a good answer to why: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks so much! But I've changed it but still nothing.

Comment: It looks like this now         @Override  
         public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
             if("Ringtone/Notification".equals(item.getTitle()))
             {function1(item.getItemId());}  
             else {return false;}  
         return true;  
         }

Comment: You should probably debug your application and put a breakpoint in that method to be sure everything is working as you expect it to.